# Equilibrium condition in a cart on a inclined plane

Tags: mechanical-engineering

The question goes as follows

The exercise machine consists of a lightweight cart which is mounted on small rollers so that it is freeto move along the inclined ramp.Two cables are attached to the cart-one for each hand.if the hands are together so that the cables are parallel and if each cable lies essentially in a vertical plane,the question is to deter the force $P$ which each hand must exert on its cable on order to maintain an equilibrium position.

[image]

I tried writing the equation for equilibrium as

$$2P=mg\sin(\theta)$$ from the FBD of cart and man together.However this is not yielding correct result.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: A homework question - not falling for this one....

Comment: @SolarMike I want to solve this question myself but my doubt is that when we consider the FBD of man and cart together should we consider the force P the man exerts on the cable.

Comment: You said that you got your equation from a FBD.  I would suggest that you post your free-body diagram, so that if it is wrong we can help you with it. If you got the FBD wrong, 100% guarantee you get the wrong answer.  It does look like you've drawn force arrows on the picture.  Note that that is NOT a FBD.  You need a separate diagram where you separate the body from its surroundings, i.e. a *free* body diagram.  If you take a shortcut and just draw arrows on the problem statement, you will very often get yourself confused. I used to teach Statics and saw many students get confused this way.

Answer (score 1):

We are not here to do your homework for you, so we will only point you in the right direction so that *you* can solve the problem.

Start by finding the force required in the direction of the rope to hold the cart stationary.  That's the force the sum of the two ropes must apply.

Note that the tension of a rope is the same everywhere.  The force it exerts on one end is the same as it exerts on the other.